# Number of processors - MacBook Pro late 2013 i5

Tags: julia

I am using Julia and was wondering when I did the following:

```
julia> addprocs()
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> workers()
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> nprocs()
5
```

I thought that my MacBook just has 4 cores? Where does the 5th come from?

Answer (score 5):

[`nprocs()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Base.Distributed.nprocs) does not return the number of processors — it's the number of *processes*.  As the help states, [`addprocs()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Base.Distributed.addprocs) is equivalent to `addprocs(Sys.CPU_CORES)`.  That is, it adds that many new workers.  The general idea is that your master node (node 1) isn't going to do much work besides distributing the work out to all the workers (nodes 2-5).

Also note that your CPU is kinda fudging the truth to you (and Julia) — you really only have two physical cores.  In many cases for computationally heavy code, the virtual cores aren't going to do much for you.

Comment: For those interested, the number of physical cores can be obtained with the `Hwloc.jl` package as in `Hwloc.num_physical_cores()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check help for `addprocs()` (press `?` and write `addprocs`) you will find that it add `Sys.CPU_CORES` number of processes by default.

Note that only workers listed by `workers()` will be used to execute computations, so actually you are going to use 4 cores in your case, which you can e.g. check like this:

```
julia> addprocs()
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> workers()
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> procs()
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> pmap(i -> myid(), 1:16)
16-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 5
 3
 4
 3
 2
 5
 4
 3
 2
 5
 4
 3
 2
 5
 4

julia> @everywhere foo() = 2^(8*myid())

julia> @parallel (+) for i in 1:16
           myid() > 1
       end
16
```

In the last loop we see that for all invocations of `myid()` it returned value greater than `1`.

Additionally if you check help of `pmap` and `@parallel` it states in both cases that they use *workers* only to perform computations.